# Installing APK - Cannot open file on Android 8.0

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, cordova

I have built a basic mobile app using Cordova (CLI 6.1.1) and Visual Studio. Everything works fine and I've managed to publish this app to IOS. I am unable to publish the app to Google Play due to their restrictions on Gaming so I need to offer this as a download from my site.

I have successfully built a release version and this installs OK on In addition when installing this which installs perfectly fine on a HTC One M8 Android version 6.0 however when trying to install on a device with version 8.0 installed, the device says "cannot open file" when clicking on the apk..?

I have enabled "Unknown sources" settings on the device which is expected.

Any ideas whether this can be resolved by further configuration on Cordova CLI, do I need to update any SDK's installed on my machine?  Any advice would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty sure you don't have the SDK v8 installed locally.

Answer (score -1):

you can try these :

1. allow unknown sources from the security tab
2. make sure your file extension is "apk"
3. make sure your file is not damaged (you can verify the md5 on the apk)
4. Go to settings/application manager/ and trigger the menu option to reset app preferences. When you attempt to open the apk make sure you select the android or Google package installer or whatever is proper for apk installation.